# How to parse Array with Alamofire 5

Tags: arrays, json, swift, alamofire, decode

I need help in decoding json data with Alamofire 5.
I'm confused about this array which I cannot decode....

```
[
    {
        "Date": "2022-08-08T00:00:00",
        "Day": "Fri",
        "AbsenceCount": 0,
        "AbsenceRequestComments": "Request permitted",
        "Color": "No",
        "IsRequestPermitted": true
    },
    {
        "Date": "2022-09-09T00:00:00",
        "Day": "Sat",
        "AbsenceCount": 0,
        "AbsenceRequestComments": "Request permitted",
        "Color": "No",
        "IsRequestPermitted": true
    },
    {
        "Date": "2022-12-15T00:00:00",
        "Day": "Sun",
        "AbsenceCount": 0,
        "AbsenceRequestComments": "Request permitted",
        "Color": "No",
        "IsRequestPermitted": true
    }
]
```

I'm trying all from this stackoverflow and didn't find something helpful for my case. Also I tried responseString, responseData, responseJSON and finaly responseDecodableOf with Codable model.

```
let request = AF.request(requestURL, method: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: returnHeader())
    .validate()
    .responseDecodable(of: [CoverCheckForDay].self) { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            guard let value = response.value else { failure(""); return }
            success(value)
        case .failure(let error):
            failure(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

My model

```
struct CoverCheckForDay: Codable {
    let date: String
    let day: String
    let absenceCount: Int
    let absenceRequestComments: String
    let color: String
    let isRequestPermitted: Bool

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case date = "Date"
        case day = "Day"
        case absenceCount = "AbsenceCount"
        case absenceRequestComments = "AbsenceRequestComments"
        case color = "Color"
        case isRequestPermitted = "IsRequestPermitted"
    }
}
```

I'm getting errors of invalid type, also in case of responseString I had some string: "\" . That's all, I'll be very thankfull for your help, thanks!

EDIT: error from alamofire

```
▿ Optional<AFError>
  ▿ some : AFError
    ▿ responseSerializationFailed : 1 element
      ▿ reason : ResponseSerializationFailureReason
        ▿ decodingFailed : 1 element
          ▿ error : DecodingError
            ▿ typeMismatch : 2 elements
              - .0 : Swift.Array<Any>
              ▿ .1 : Context
                - codingPath : 0 elements
                - debugDescription : "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a string/data instead."
                - underlyingError : nil
```

My parameters:

```
▿ 3 elements
  ▿ 0 : 2 elements
    - key : "employeeId"
    - value : 13558
  ▿ 1 : 2 elements
    - key : "dates"
    ▿ value : 3 elements
      ▿ 0 : CoverRequestArray
        ▿ date : Optional<String>
          - some : "01/09/2022"
        ▿ day : Optional<String>
          - some : "Thu"
      ▿ 1 : CoverRequestArray
        ▿ date : Optional<String>
          - some : "02/09/2022"
        ▿ day : Optional<String>
          - some : "Fri"
      ▿ 2 : CoverRequestArray
        ▿ date : Optional<String>
          - some : "03/09/2022"
        ▿ day : Optional<String>
          - some : "Sat"
  ▿ 2 : 2 elements
    - key : "siteId"
    - value : 440
```

Comment: I guess an error is thrown? What's the print of `error`??

Comment: Hi, I added error from alamofire

Comment: Could you print `String(data: response.data!, encoding: .utf8)!`? I'm wondering if you aren't receiving a JSON Stringified.

Comment: Printing description of string:
▿ Optional<String>
  - some : "\"\""

Comment: So your response isn't the expected JSON, especially if it clearly says "2 bytes", you see that the whole sample you can can fit into two bytes... So the issue lies within the request...

Comment: thanks for your answer. May it be problem with input and encoding parameters? I sent params like this as [String: Any], so maybe date isn't recorded properly to server? But I found thing, that if I sent much days like 15+ server return 404, if less return 200. Looks like my parameters goods for it. 
I added parameters to topic

Comment: depending on what the server expect, 
you may want to try a different `encoding` for your parameters in the request, such as `encoding: JSONEncoding.default`,

Comment: We don't know the doc of the API. Do you have a sample doc? A cURL equivalent? Can you make it work on Postman?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So guys problem was in server side with wrong method I guess. Backend developer from side **did GET method with input data body**. Web says that from 2019 Apple violate send body data with GET.

Thanks everyone for your answers, so in some occasional it's my failure that I didn't checked this first.

Screen from postman:
[image: Screen from postman]

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try decoding like this:

In your file but outside your struct add:

```
typealias CoverCheck = [CoverCheckForDay]
```

and decode like:

```
AF.request(requestURL, method: .get)
        .response{ response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let data):
                let newJSONDecoder = JSONDecoder()
                if let result = try? newJSONDecoder.decode(CoverCheck.self, from: data!){
                   print(result)
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I tried this one and it's didn't worked. Here is print of data: ▿ Optional<Data>
  ▿ some : 2 bytes
    - count : 2
    ▿ pointer : 0x00000003075f9128
      - pointerValue : 13008605480
    ▿ bytes : 2 elements
      - 0 : 34
      - 1 : 34

Answer (score 0):

Your output is an empty string, your custom odd *failure-value*.

The problem is that the handling of the `success` case is wrong.

`.success` has a non-optional associated value like `.failure` which is the decoded object.

Change the code to something like

```
.responseDecodable(of: [CoverCheckForDay].self) { response in
    switch response.result {
    case .success(let coverCheckArray):
        success(coverCheckArray)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. but I'm not really understand what will differ from my case. This response don't return success in any case, it fails because of error which I added to post..